# Scanner doesn't scan

Tags: scanner, scanning

Ubuntu 12.04. HP Scanjet 2400. Simple Scan 3.43 won't work. It just keeps loading forever. I "turned it off and on again (R)" and now it just says it can't connect to the scanner, despite the correct model showing on the device list dropdown.

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 03f0:0a01 Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 2400c

$ sane-find-scanner 
found USB scanner (vendor=0x03f0 [Hewlett-Packard], product=0x0a01 [hp scanjet scanner], chip=GL646_HP) at libusb:002:003

$ scanimage -L
device `genesys:libusb:002:003' is a Hewlett Packard ScanJet 2400c flatbed scanner
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as "This describes a problem that can't be reproduced that seemingly went away on its own or was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It's off-topic as it's unlikely to help future readers." (see first answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried again and moved the scanner a bit and it works now. I suspect it's a bad USB cable.